# GSON - 1 parent, multiple children

Tags: java, android, json, gson

In the below JSON, you'll see that there are many objects that have a 'groups' child (these all seem to be the same), and that those groups have a child named 'items' (these are different depending on the group's parent).

My question:

is it possible to make 1 'groups' class that's added to multiple objects but still have the correct 'items' class be parsed by GSON?

Maybe something like:

```
public List<Item<T>> items
```

not sure how to go about this and trying to avoid writing a ton of redundant 'groups' classes.

Thanks in advance!

**Pasting the JSON string put me over the character limit so I posted it up on pastebin.  You can find it [by clicking here](http://pastebin.com/BtC1yad5)**

Comment: that JSON is a bummer to parse with plain GSON, you have mixed type groups in a list. I guess only way is to specify a custom parser for them.

Comment: I didn't even know that was a thing. Still pretty green with gson. I looked it up and that looks like the right move. Put this as an answer with a small example (in case others come across this) and I'll hit you with a check mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the JSON you're trying to deserialize is that it contains mixed elements as `groups` items thus it is impossible to just write a POJO to fit that structure.

In fact you'll have at some point a field like this:

```
ArrayList<Group> groups;
```

But `Group` can change actual type from item to item in the list, so what you can do at this point is to build a general father `GenericGroup<T>` class like this:

```
public class GenericGroup<T> {

    String type;
    String name;
    ArrayList<T> items;

    public ArrayList<T> getItems(){
        return items;
    }

    public static class SomeGroup extends GenericGroup<SomeItem>{}
    public static class SomeOtherGroup extends GenericGroup<SomeOtherItem>{}

}
```

Done this, you should then put in the POJO model for the JSON the field:

```
ArrayList<GenericGroup> groups;
```

Now you're ready to create items of each type you need like:

```
public class SomeItemType{

    String someAttribute;
    String someOtherAttribute;
    ...

}
```

Now comes the crazy part where you'll need to write a custom GSON deserializer for the class GenericGroup:

```
public class GenericGroupDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<GenericGroup> {
    @Override
    public GenericGroup deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        String type = json.getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString();
        switch (type){
            case "someType":
                return new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), GenericGroup.SomeGroup.class);
            case "someOtherType":
                return new Gson().fromJson(json.toString(), GenericGroup.SomeOtherGroup.class);
            default:
                return new GenericGroup();
        }
    }
}
```

Then finally, in your MainActivity write something like this:

```
private Gson mGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(GenericGroup.class, new GenericGroupDeserializer()).create();
```